# Prove that $\sup(S)=1$ if $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x^2 < x\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I wanted to check whether I have done this proof right.  I have not fully convinced myself.

Proof:
Let $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x^2 < x\}$.  Since $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we know that $x^2 > 0$, by a result of the positivity axioms, it follows that $x > 0$.  Now if $x^2 < x$, then $x < 1$. Then by definition of $S$, $1$ is an upper bound for $S$.  Since $S$ is bounded above, then by the Completeness Axiom, there exists a least upper bound, $\sup S$, such that $\sup S \leq 1$.  So $x < \sup S \leq 1$, then $x^2 < x < \sup S \leq 1$.  Then $1 < \sup S \leq 1$.  Therefore $\sup S=1$.

Comment: How are you concluding $1\lt\sup S\leq 1$? That would be impossible in any case (you cannot have $1\lt 1$). I agree that you have established that $\sup(S)\leq 1$, but you have not shown that it is *exactly* $1$. *Hint:* Show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $x$ in $S$ with $1-\epsilon\lt x\leq 1$.

Comment: In this case, the set is simple enough that we can find $S$ explicitly by solving $x^2 < x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $1^2=1$, and you know that $f(x)=x$ grows slower than $g(x)=x^2$ for $x>1$, since $f'(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=2x$, and $2x>1$ for $x>1$. It follows that $x^2-x<0 $ for $x>1$.
Now use too, the fact that $x(x-1)<0$ for $0<x<1$

Answer (score 0):

Solving the inequality, we have $S=(0,1)$; I do not see the problem with $\sup S=1$