# Give that $S = \{x \in\mathbb{R} \colon x^2<x\}$, prove that $\sup S =1$

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I found the question [Prove that $\sup(S)=1$ if $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}| x^2 < x\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/prove-that-sups-1-if-s-x-in-mathbbr-x2-x), but I don't quite understand the answer.

---

This is my approach:

$S\equiv\{x\in\mathbb{R}\vert x^2<x\}\equiv\{x\in\mathbb{R}\vert 0<x<1\}\equiv\{x\in\mathbb{R}\vert 0<x^2<1\}$, by the definition of $S$, $S$ is bounded above and $\sup S = 1$. Now assume that $1$ is not the supremum but is $b$ where $b>1$ or $b<1$.

If $b>1$, then we can pick $\epsilon=\frac{b^2+1}{2b}$ such that $b-\epsilon<b$.

Then we can have $$(b-\epsilon)^2=b^2-2b\epsilon +\epsilon^2>b^2-2b\epsilon=1\Rightarrow b-\epsilon>1$$
This gives a contraction that $b$ is the least upper bound.

If $b<1$, let $\epsilon=\frac{1-b^2}{2b+1}$, then 
$$(b+\epsilon)^2=b^2+2b\epsilon+\epsilon^2<b^2+\epsilon(2b+1)=1\Rightarrow b+\epsilon<1$$

This contracts that $b$ is an upper bound, hence $\sup S =1$

---

I just follow the step from the text book. Could anyone give me a suggestion to write a better proof or explain more detail on the answer I linked? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: choose $x = \frac{b+1}{2}$, if b>1, this x contradicts that is supermum because it is greater than 1 and less than b, if b<1, this x is in S but greater than b, so b=1.

Comment: $0<x<1$ is not equivalent to $0<x^2<1$.

Comment: Case $b>1$ is not requires in your arguments, as said by D.A.

Comment: If you prove that $S=\{x: 0<x<1\}$ is it not clear that $\sup S =1$?

Comment: Why do you assume the sup  is equal to 1? and once you do state the sup is equal to 1, why do you continue to write anything at all.  The exercise was to prove the sup was 1.  Once you state that you are done.  So why didn't you stop after the first sentence?

Comment: Basically you are beginning by assuming what you want to prove.  Why is $x^2 < x$ the same as $0 < x < 1$?  (Hint: It isn't.)  Then why is it by definition that {0<x <1} is bounded above? (It's easy and obvious but it isn't by definition).  And why is the sup = 1?  (It's easy and obvious and once you show it in one case it should be true for all, but it's not by definition.)  Then once you state sup = 1 you've achieved you goal. So what is left to prove  All the rest is proving if $b < 1$ or $b > 1$ then $b \ne 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Show that S is bounded above.

Show that if x >= 1 then x is not in S.  Then  1 is greater than all elements of S so S is bounded above and 1 is an upper bound. (Although you don't know if it is the least upper bound yet.)

In your proof you just stated this without proving or showing anything.

Step 2:  Show that if b < 1, then b is not an upper bound.

Show that if b < 1 then there is an x with b < x < 1 such that x is in S.  In other words if b < 1 then there is an x; b < x < 1 such that $x^2 < x $.  As b < x $\in$ S b can't be an upper bound.  As b was arbitrary, 1 is the least upper bound.

(You won't need any epsilon proofs at all.  In fact they'll just be too hard.)